# Should we stay out of causes in which we have no personal interest?

Tags: parshat-korach

A follower of Korach, named On, was swayed by his wife to stay out of the rebellion and was saved:

> Rav says: On, son of Peleth -- his wife saved him. She said to him: "What is the difference to you? If this Master [Moses] is the great one, you are the student. And if this Master, [Korach], is the great one, you are the student. [Why are you involving yourself in this matter?]"
> On said to her: What shall I do? I was one of those who took counsel and I took an oath with them [that I would be with them]... She said to him: "Sit, for I will save you." She gave him wine to drink and caused him to become drunk and laid him on a bed [inside their tent]. She sat at the entrance of the tent and exposed her hair [as though she were bathing]. Anyone who came and saw her stepped back. In the meantime [the assembly of Korach] was swallowed into the ground, [but On was spared]. [[Sanhedrin 109b-110a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.109b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]

Commentators deem her a righteous woman.  Perhaps women, much more than men, put home and family first -- rather then causes and ideology.  But is this always the right attitude: "What's in it for me?  If nothing, I should stay out"?  Any sources?

Comment: It's much deeper. She's poking a hole in Korach's fantasy that he's all about "everyone is holy" ... *you realize that pretty soon it's going to be "everyone is holy but Korach is holiest?" (Think *Animal Farm.*)

Comment: Causes and ideology are great to get involved in, if it’s for the sake of heaven. The Mishnah in Avos says this “cause” is the epitome of not for the sake of heaven. His wife realized this and pointed it out. Had it of been for the sake of heaven he would’ve answered her that he doesn’t care if he’s the student, so long as the honor of Hashem is restored. With her words, he realized himself he had erred and this cause was really faulty

Comment: Downvoter: Explain.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better put that we should stay out  CONTROVERSIAL and "us against them" causes in which we have no personal interest.

Comment: You know what they said about R' Aharon Soloveitchik zt"l -- *it's not just that he's the only rosh yeshiva of his caliber going out and protesting about Biafra. He's the only rosh yeshiva of his caliber who knows what Biafra is.*

Answer (score 1):

The main lesson to be learnt which the [Gemoro](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.110a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) you quote brings is culled from [Mishlei 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.14.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> חַכְמ֣וֹת נָ֭שִׁים בָּנְתָ֣ה בֵיתָ֑הּ
>
> The wisest of women builds her house

Ultimately, it was through an astute understanding of the situation that she was able prevent her husband from meeting his untimely death. This heightened awareness stems from a unique acuity that only women are blessed with known as בינה יתירה – literally, ‘additional understanding’. (Refer to [Niddah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.45b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)<sup>1</sup>)

HaRav Tzadok HaKohen of Lublin זצ"ל adds that this female trait is rooted in the heart, whilst חכמה, wisdom, belongs to the male consciousness and stems from the brain.

Quoting the Zohar<sup>2</sup> he writes:

> חכמה ובינה הם אבא ואימא
>
> Wisdom and understanding – they are the father (i.e. wisdom) and the mother (i.e. understanding)<sup>3</sup>

What this means to say is that essentially, women have an intuitive and holistic understanding of the world around them. As their understanding originates from the heart, they are in tune with their emotions and have an extra sensory perception that males lack. Thus, Rav Tzadok comments that this trait of בינה is something that is a "דבר ברור" – “a precise matter”.<sup>4</sup>  In short, women can assess a situation with a heightened degree of clarity, a trait that plays a huge role within the home. It is with this attribute that they are able to judge the family balance noting which areas require greater care and attention.

Indeed, the Maharal writes in [Derech Chaim on Pirkei Avos 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Chayim.1.5.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> האשה יסוד מציאות הבית ויש ללכת אחר עצתה
>
> The woman is the foundation, (and is thus) the reality of the home, and one should resultantly follow her advice

Thus we see from this episode how a righteous woman was able to use her innate understanding of a situation which helped save her husband.

---

<sup>1</sup>

> מלמד שנתן הקב"ה בינה יתירה באשה יותר מבאיש
>
> This teaches that Hashem provides an additional understanding with women, more so than with men

<sup>2</sup> Zohar Parshas Yisro 5:1

<sup>3</sup> [Refer to Dover Tzedek p.43](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9619&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=) (last paragraph on page)

<sup>4</sup> [Refer to Dover Tzedek p.48](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9619&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=)

Comment: I understand the importance of women in that respect, but my question was: Can you use "What's in it for me?" as an excuse to stay out of causes?

Comment: So perhaps remove the line "What is the lesson from her behavior?" as that opens it up to wider interpretation?

Comment: done---------------